# ReactJS Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

```
    var divArr = [
       '<div>布吉岛啊</div>',
       '<div>呵呵呵</div>',
    ];
    ReactDOM.render(
       <div>{divArr}</div>,
       document.getElementById("example")
    );
```

but it's error:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the top-level render call using . See [warning-keys][1] for more information.

and I don't know how to insert the 'key'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to put `unique key` inside the `array div` check my code

```
var divArr = [
 '<div key='1'>布吉岛啊</div>',
 '<div key='2'>呵呵呵</div>',
];
ReactDOM.render(
   <div>{divArr}</div>,
   document.getElementById("example")
);
```

Comment: please mark my answer as a right answer so that others can get help :)

Comment: OK~but need to wait 3 mins